# If I have a numerator and denominator as two variables, how can I know if they form an integer?

Tags: c++

For example, if I have int numerator = 8, and int denominator = 2, this will form the integer 4. But how can I check that in c++?

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
if (numerator % denominator == 0)
{
return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Why didn't you test out your code? It's perfectly fine.

Comment: i did test it but it just felt wrong.

Comment: You'd better not program on feeling for now, better stick to the hard facts ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're right, but easier:

```
return numerator % denominator == 0;
```